# Looking for help on Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Below is what I am trying to accomplish in excel.  I need to find the correct code to fill the series as I need to go to around 7Million.  Your help is greatly appreciated and will save me hours of manual work

```
A1  0
A2  50
A3  50
A4  100
A5  100
A6  150
A7  150
A8  200
A9  200
A10 250
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your A11 formula would look like this:

```
=IF(A9+50=A10,A10,A10+50)
```

You would have to copy and paste this formula around 140,000 times which may cause your Excel to crash. If Excel becomes painfully slow or crashes, copy all formulae and paste as values to improve performance.

Answer (score 2):

With 0 in A1 and 50 in A2 put this in A3 and fill down to A280000.

```
=A2+(A2=A1)*50
```

Answer (score 2):

For total simplicity's sake, you could also just use this in `A11` and drag down:

```
=A9+50
```

Comment: Has anyone speed tested these? A while back I thought I had the fastest at 1.07 sec for 280K rows but I think this would beat it providing the seeded values were in place.

Answer (score 1):

Turn the calculation to manual.  in A1 type 0.  In A2 type `= A1 + 1`. In B2

```
=(2*A2+1+(-1)^(A2+1))*12.5
```

Select A2:B2 and fill/drag/copy down to however Nth number you need the series to. 
Turn the calculation back to Automatic.

If still slow, fill a VBA (1 to N, 1 to 1) array and dump back to excel or save as csv.

Comment: This might be cracking walnuts with a sledgehammer. Best to keep 250K rows of formulas as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

another way to generate the series because there are just not enough posted already 8)

```
=ROUNDDOWN(ROW(A1)/2,0)*50
```

Place where ever you like and copy down.

Answer (score 0):

If your values are in the column `B` us the following code in all cells of that column, except for B1 being `0`:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("B" & ROW() - 1)+50)
```

Comment: And of course, if they are in column A just change the B to an A.

Comment: Over a quarter million INDIRECTs. That would be an interesting worksheet/workbook to use.

Comment: I needed to copy the output into another program(Spotfire)